# Using PhoneGap/Cordova and detecting if user is actually connected to a network

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

We are using Cordova for a hybrid project.  We ran into an issue where if the device/app sees a WiFi network, BUT the WiFi network requires authentication or a acceptance of their terms and conditions (most commonly seen for cafes, hotels, etc.).

PhoneGap/Cordova just sees the WiFi network, so a check for network is actually unreliable, because the app is seeing a network, the user is just not logged on to get remote data from the app.

Has anyone dealt with this or handled these types of situations?  How did you approach or work through a solution.  Any code snippets?

Comment: have you seen this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_connection_connection.md.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there's a plugin for this.

**If you rely on a specific backend server:**

Simply checking if the device is online may not be enough as the server (for whatever reason) may be offline.

So I ended up having a RESTful Service like (node.js/express):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.jsonp({status: 'OK'});
});
```

that simply returns "OK" and checking the connection in several situations.

**If you just need to know if you're online:**

In this case I would check for some generally available website and see if it can be accessed. Maybe the [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) could help with this as it can load websites in the background and report errors if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is on online, open HEAD request for a known URL. If the request works, you're all set. If it fails, the user might be in a captive portal.

Comment: we tried this but it was kind of unreliable in what we were trying to do.  we would get a response sometimes and others not.  Not sure if we did it correctly.  Any code samples of your idea?